# Is any better way to handle JSON in R | performance improvement

Tags: json, r

**Data Preparation**

```
 comp <- 
 c('[{"id": 28, "name": "Google"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Microsoft"}]', 
 '[{"id": 32, "name": "Microsoft"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Facebook"}]')
 id = c(1,2)
 jsonData = as.data.frame(id,comp)
 jsonData
                                                                   id
[{"id": 28, "name": "Google"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Microsoft"}]     1
[{"id": 32, "name": "Microsoft"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Facebook"}]  2
```

I am not sure why 'comp' not came as column name and why 'id' came later if it's defined before, Also its giving error if I define 'as.data.frame(comp,id)'

Now I am dealing with JSON data

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

data <- jsonData %>% mutate(x = lapply(comp,fromJSON)) %>% unnest(x)
data
  id id1      name
1  1  28    Google
2  1  12 Microsoft
3  2  32 Microsoft
4  2 878  Facebook
```

Is there any better way to deal with JSON in R, like any library which directly convert JSON to normal column, currently I am taking small data so its look easy but I have multiple columns having JSON input and Its too much performance hit for my report

Comment: "convert JSON to normal column" ? "performance hit" ?

Comment: I means convert JSON value i.e. '{"id": 28, "name": "Google"}' to normal column of data table so we can apply dplyr queries, otherwise dplyr takes the JSON as plain text. The way I am converting it takes minutes when I processes it over half million such JSON columns which is performance hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is text. Text parsing is slow. Also not sure why `library(dplyr)` is there since it comes with the `tidyverse`. And, you should consider reading up on how to make data frames.

Regardless. We'll make an representative example: 500,000 rows:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_frame(
  id = rep(c(1L, 2L), 250000),
  comp = rep(c(
    '[{"id": 28, "name": "Google"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Microsoft"}]', 
    '[{"id": 32, "name": "Microsoft"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Facebook"}]'
  ), 250000)
) -> xdf
```

There are *many* JSON processing packages in R. Test out a few. This uses `ndjson` which has a function `flatten()` which takes a character vector of JSON strings and makes a "completely flat" structure from it.

I'm only using different data frame variables for explanatory clarity and benchmarking later.

```
pull(xdf, comp) %>% 
  ndjson::flatten() %>% 
  bind_cols(select(xdf, id)) -> ydf
```

That makes:

```
ydf
## Source: local data table [500,000 x 5]
## 
## # A tibble: 500,000 x 5
##    `0.id` `0.name`  `1.id` `1.name`     id
##     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <int>
##  1    28. Google       12. Microsoft     1
##  2    32. Microsoft   878. Facebook      2
##  3    28. Google       12. Microsoft     1
##  4    32. Microsoft   878. Facebook      2
##  5    28. Google       12. Microsoft     1
##  6    32. Microsoft   878. Facebook      2
##  7    28. Google       12. Microsoft     1
##  8    32. Microsoft   878. Facebook      2
##  9    28. Google       12. Microsoft     1
## 10    32. Microsoft   878. Facebook      2
## # ... with 499,990 more rows
```

We can turn that back into a more tidy data frame:

```
bind_rows(
  select(ydf, id = id, id1=`0.id`, name=`0.name`),
  select(ydf, id = id, id1=`1.id`, name=`1.name`)
) %>% 
  mutate(id1 = as.integer(id1))
## Source: local data table [1,000,000 x 3]
## 
## # A tibble: 1,000,000 x 3
##       id   id1 name     
##    <int> <int> <chr>    
##  1     1    28 Google   
##  2     2    32 Microsoft
##  3     1    28 Google   
##  4     2    32 Microsoft
##  5     1    28 Google   
##  6     2    32 Microsoft
##  7     1    28 Google   
##  8     2    32 Microsoft
##  9     1    28 Google   
## 10     2    32 Microsoft
## # ... with 999,990 more rows
```

Now, we'll benchmark with 1,000 rows since I'm not waiting for the full 500,000 run to microbenchmark:

```
data_frame(
  id = rep(c(1L, 2L), 500),
  comp = rep(c(
    '[{"id": 28, "name": "Google"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Microsoft"}]', 
    '[{"id": 32, "name": "Microsoft"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Facebook"}]'
  ), 500)
) -> xdf

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  faster = {
    pull(xdf, comp) %>% 
      ndjson::flatten() %>% 
      bind_cols(select(xdf, id)) -> ydf

    bind_rows(
      select(ydf, id = id, id1=`0.id`, name=`0.name`),
      select(ydf, id = id, id1=`1.id`, name=`1.name`)
    ) %>% 
      mutate(id1 = as.integer(id1))
  }
)
## Unit: milliseconds
##    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  faster 12.46409 13.71483 14.73997 14.40582 15.47529 21.09543   100
```

So:

- 15ms for 1,000 rows
- 15ms * 500 = 7.5s for 500,000

If you're not pedantic about the `id1` column needing to be an integer, you can likely shave off a few ms.

There are other approaches. And, if you regularly work with columns of JSON data, I highly recommend checking out Apache Drill and the `sergeant` package.

Comment: thanks, It will help me a lot also gives data point to research